# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at eval (eventtargetinterruptsource.js) while using ng-idle/ng-keepalive in angular 8

Tags: angular, keep-alive, ng-idle

I want to use ng-idle/ng-keepalive in my angular 8 project, I tried installing many versions of them, but in console it is showing this error only

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at eval (eventtargetinterruptsource.js:39:70)

Can you tell me which version should i install that would be compatible with Angular version 8

I installed the version for ng-idle/keepalive by using this [version guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core?activeTab=versions)

Comment: Which version of ng-idle/keepalive did you install?

Comment: i tried installing the 8,7,6 versions provided in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-idle/core?activeTab=versions)  and recently i installed 2.0.0-beta.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use v8.0.0-beta.4.

You can check the compatible version of most of npm libraries by following these steps.

1. Go to GitHub source repository. In this case, it's https://github.com/moribvndvs/ng2-idle
2. Open `package.json` file and check which version of angular is this library's latest version compatible with. `"dependencies" -> "@angular/core"`
3. If it is not the version you want, you try to switch to another `tag` from `Switch branches/tags` dropdown.[image]

Comment: thanks for this insight. I was mistaken about the angular version I am using. I am using angular 5, so i installed ng-idle/keepalive [this](npm install --save @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.15 @ng-idle/keepalive@2.0.0-beta.15). Now it is not showing that error. But the code I implemented for ng-idle is not working. Do i have to change the import also?  right now i am importing this way : import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot()

Comment: import { Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { Keepalive } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
Please help. Thanks

Comment: @SalviRawat, please follow steps in https://github.com/moribvndvs/ng2-idle-example